# innerHTML and document.getElementbyId().value conflicting?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I've run into a bit of a problem. I'm using   `document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML` to set the value of a `<li>`. Then, later in the code, I'm accessing it using `document.getElementById("foo").value`. However, this returns "undefined". The code looks a bit like this:

```
document.getElementById("myElement").innerHTML = "This is a test";
...
var v = document.getElementById("myElement").value; // Returns "undefined"
```

I've tried multiple ways to fix this, to no avail. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: If you debug that code, does anything change when you assign the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` is for `<form>` elements like `<input>`, `<progressbar>` etc, for `<li>` you should use `innerHTML` as you already do.

Answer (score 1):

`value` attribute is available for inputs. As you set `innerHTML`, you can get it just referencing it as: `document.getElementById("myElemento").innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

The element must be an input field to have a value. Li is not an input field, so value is undefined.